# Switchless enums in Dart

Tags: dart, oop, enums, hashmap, switch-statement

I want to do something like this in Dart

```
enum Result {
  dns,
  dnf,
  dnq,
  finish,
  active;

  get description {
    switch(this){
    case dns: return 'Not Started';
    case dnf: return 'Disqualified';
    case dnq: return 'Disqualified';
    case finish: return 'Finished';
    case active: return 'Underway';
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works, but I'm bothered by the switch. I have an instinct that there should be a way to do this without the switch -- perhaps with a Map? But I can't figure out how.

I tried this

```
enum Result {
  dns,
  dnf,
  dnq,
  finish,
  active;

  final Map  _description = {
    dns: 'Not Started',
    dnf: 'Disqualified',
    dnq: 'Disqualified',
    finish: 'Finished',
    active: 'Underway'
  };

  get description => _description[this];

}
```

but that apparently won't work because dart says _description "depends on itself". I don't see how it does depend on itself any more than the version with the switch -- but hey, the compiler says so. Is this a dart bug, or am I missing something?  Is there a better way to create enums that have auxiliary getters?

It would be great if there was a way that didn't require typing the enum identifiers twice and having to keep the copies aligned -- like, you know, an OO way.

Comment: The reason it depends on itself is that `_description` is a an *instance* field. If you made it static, things would work. Being an instance field, creating the `dns` object requires initializing a field with a map containing itself as a key. It can't do that.
Static fields are lazily initialized, so it can be created after all of the enum values have been created. 

Using the answer below is better, this is just to explain the error message.

Comment: That was it, @Irn thanks! Good explanation too.

Comment: The weird thing is that things like "dns" seem static, but as you say @irn, they are really a "whole object" not just an enum constant. So they include the Map -- which isn't static.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich FYI, the person you're replying to is **L**asse **R**. (H.) **N**ielsen from the Dart language team.  "lrn" starts with a lowercase L, not with an I.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this like:

```dart
enum Result {
  dns('Not Started'),
  dnf('Did Not Finish'),
  dnq('Disqualified'),
  finish('Finished'),
  active('Underway');
  
  const Result(this.description);
  
  final description;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because sometimes the descriptions will be the same for two different enum tags -- and I don't want to be storing strings everywhere instead of ints.  But I read the comment about _description needing to be static. THAT was the problem. And they give a good explanation in the comment.  Perhaps edit the above answer a little and I'll endorse it.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich You can still serialize the enums as ints by using the index, i.e. `Result.dns.index`. Alternatively, you can add another "id" field to hold the int value you want.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich "sometimes the descriptions will be the same for two different enum tags -- and I don't want to be storing strings everywhere" String literals are [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). You will not have extra copies of the same string in memory.

Comment: Beware using Result... that has a meaning in package:async

Comment: Thanks @RandalSchwartz. I switched to "Outcome" -- hope that's name collision safe.